# For loop not looping over all files in batch-file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am a newbie to batch-files so please be gentle! I've been trying to construct a simple batch file in order to rename thousands of text files according to a particular naming convention. Due to the fragmented nature of the file locations, I was hoping to run the batch-file from within the same folder as the target text files.

Although the script seems to execute fine on a single file when run, it does not loop over all the files in the same folder and I'm not sure why! If I run the script multiple times, eventually every file will become translated but obviously this is not ideal. Any help greatly appreciated!

Code is below:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%a in ("*.txt") do (
   set name=%%~Na
   set prefix=QX
   set newName=!prefix!!name:~0,1!X!name:~1,2!!name:~3!
   ren "%%a" "!newName!%%~Xa"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like this :

```
@echo off
set prefix=QX

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.txt /b') do (
                                  set name=%%~Na
                                  set newName=%prefix%!name:~0,1!X!name:~1,2!!name:~3!
                                  ren "%%a" "!newName!%%~Xa")
```